# Laravel 6 unique on validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request

I am trying to validate data during user update profile...the update works perfectly fine when there is no validation, but when i try to validate data using requests i am unable to make change in user data i get the duplicate entry error when i try to update for example a name field and leave email field as it is...

This is what i have tried...
UpdateProfileRequest Request below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\User;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;



class UpdateProfileRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        
        return [
           
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users,'.$this->id, 
            'organization'=>'required',
            'location'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
            'email' => 'required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'.$this->id,
            /*'password'=>'required'*/
            
        ];
        
   
    }
}
```

UseController...update method

```
   public function update(UpdateProfileRequest $request)
    {
           
        $user = auth()->user();

        $user->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'organization' => $request->organization,
            'location' => $request->location,
            'email' => $request->email,
            /*'password' => Hash::make($request->password)*/
        ]);
```

Below is my form in edit.blade.php in view

```
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.update') }}">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-user" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Name') }}</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="organization" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-building-o" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Organization') }}</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="organization" type="text" class="form-control @error('organization') is-invalid @enderror" name="organization" value="{{ $user->organization }}" required autocomplete="organization" autofocus>

                   
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="location" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Location') }}</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="location" type="text" class="form-control @error('location') is-invalid @enderror" name="location" value="{{ $user->location }}" required autocomplete="location" autofocus>

                   
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-envelope" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}" required autocomplete="email">

                    
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--<div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-key" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Password') }}</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">
                        <small>Enter password/<small style="color:#3490dc;">New password</small></small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-key" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                        <small>Retype password/<small style="color:#3490dc;">New password</small></small>
                    </div>
                </div>-->

                <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            {{ __('Update') }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'organization', 'location', 'email', 'password', 
       
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    


}
```

I want to edit profile such that name and email address are unique, but allow same data for current user despite giving the duplicate entry error for the same user...

I will appreciate any help thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are skipping an argument to the `unique` rule. if you want to ignore a record by 'id' you still have to pass the second argument which is the column to check for uniqueness (in your case the name of the field you are validating) then you pass the 'id'` to ignore as the 3rd argument: `unique:users,email,1` ... what does `$this->input` refer to in your Request? a route parameter, input or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `rules` function in `UpdateProfileRequest` class with below function:

```
public function rules()
{   
    return [
            'name' => ['required','string', 'max:255',
                        Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) use($this) {
                            return $query->where('name', $this->name);
                        })->ignore($this->id)
                    ],
            'organization'=>'required',
            'location'=>'required',
            'email' => ['required','string', 'email', 'max:255',
                        Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) use($this) {
                            return $query->where('email', $this->email);
                        })->ignore($this->id)
                    ]
        ];
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sunshant Yadav thanks for the answer it looks working but it has a small syntax error "can not use  $this as lexical variable "

Comment: @mhtl I just given sample code and didn't tested, so it may contain small syntax error which you can solve easily when you implement it.

Comment: I am trying to play around with that syntax error and i am trying to quickly find a solution to that but the only way i achieved is to remove use ($this) function but it drives me back to the previous error...duplicate entry "the name and email is already taken...."thanks once again for the answer

Comment: why are you adding wheres to the unique rule? the rule itself will already be checking those conditions ... and you can use `$this` in the closure automatically (not using a `use` statement) as it references the object the closure was created in (unless the closure is bound otherwise)